# In JS validation - trying to remove spaces from text-box, but getting undefined value

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I want to remove leading and trailing spaces from the values provided in a text box. For that I am using JavaScript validation. In that I have declared two variables and when I tried to check the values assigned to these variables, I am getting `undefined` as value. Can you please let me know where I am wrong?

```js
function trim(StringtoTrim){
    StringtoTrim.replace(/^\s\s*/, '');
}

function validate() 
{
    alert("in validate ");
    var value1 = myform.fname.value;
    alert(value1.value);
    var value2 = trim(value);
    alert(value2.value);
    if(value2.length != value1.length)
    {
        document.getElementById('errfn').innerHTML="please remove leading and trailing spaces ";
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myform" onsubmit="return validate();">
            First_Name
            <input type="text" name="fname"/><span id="errfn"></span>
            <br> <br>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to get value of value

```
var value1 = myform.fname;
alert(value1.value);
```

and second value is not defined

```
var value2 = trim(value);
```

it should be `value1` but still the script is more problems than that. See below

```
function validate() 
{
    alert("in validate ");
    var value1 = myform.fname.value;
    alert(value1);
    var value2 = value1.trim();
    alert(value2);
    if(value2.length != value1.length)
    {
       document.getElementById('errfn').innerHTML="please remove leading and trailing spaces ";
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ohh! seriously that was blunder. Anyways thank you. It works for me.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to mark as resolved so it may help someone else later.

Comment: can you please  tell me in which case i need to use alert(value1.value);

Comment: if your object is the DOM node ( input itself ) then you can use obj.value. but in your case value1 was already set to value of the object. so value of value is undefined.

Comment: oh! okk, one more problem I am facing. when I am using  var value2 = trim(value1); it shows me value of value2 "undefine". But when i use var value2 = value1.replace(/^\s\s*/, ''); it works for me. Could you please help why I am not able to call another function.

Comment: ah! yeah I missed that. trim is not a function in javascript. But it is a subfunction of string prototype. you need to use `var value2 = value1.trim()`

Comment: It works, thanks for your help man. You are having command in this area.

Answer (score 2):

Your own made trim function is broken, it leaves the trailing spaces.

**String** has a built in **trim()** function.
This removes all leading and trailing spaces but leaves the spaces inside the word.

`"     de mo     ".trim()`

Will result in:

`"de mo"`

In the validate function there are other problems, you try to access

in `alert(value1.value)` you try to access `myform.fname.value.value` which is invalid, this should be `alert(value1)`

`var value2 = trim(value)`, here value is undefined and should be `var value2 = trim(value1)`

Comment: Just to remind you, your regex in the trim doesn't remove trailing spaces, what was the purpose to write it?

Comment: Yeah! I just checked that. Thanks